# Emit of boolean returns "null" instead of "false" (Solidity, web3.js)

Tags: solidity, web3js

A Solidity event is supposed to emit a boolean. In case of `won = true` the transaction receipt in web3 logs `true` as expected, but if `won = false` the emit logs `null` instead `false`. I have no idea why. First I thought it is because of the same variable name, but that is not the cause.

I have this Solidity function which either emits "true" or "false"

```
event GameResult(bool won);

//My simplified contract
function lottery(uint8 guess) public payable returns(bool){
  uint8 result = 1;
  bool won = false;
  if (guess == result) {
    //Won!
    msg.sender.transfer(msg.value * 2);
    won = true;
  }
  emit GameResult(won);
}
```

UPDATE: Here is my web3 function to call the contract (only the relevant part. Full code can be found on [Github](https://github.com/rene78/Heads-Or-Tails/blob/master/src/main.js)):

```
async function play() {
  let headsOrTailsSelection = 1;

  //A test to get the emit values from the contract: true "works", "false" not
  headsOrTails.once('GameResult', function(error, event){ console.log(event.returnValues); });

  returnValue = await headsOrTails.methods.lottery(headsOrTailsSelection).send({ from: account, value: amountToBetWei });
  console.log(returnValue);
}
```

General infos:

- Currently using Ganache as a local blockchain for development
- Solidity version: ^0.5.0
- IDE: VS Code

Comment: Show your web3 code please.

Comment: @goodvibration Just added it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you try to load all past events and see if false appears there?
I tried your code in `vue` app and it's working fine.
`headsOrTails.events.GameResult(
        {
          fromBlock: 0
        },
        function(error, event) {
          console.log(event.returnValues);
        }
      );`

Comment: @Yahya Same result. The events with `true` return `true`, the ones with `false` return `null`.

Comment: can you please switch to another network? like Rinkeby
Ganache is not always good when it comes to the events.

Comment: @Yahya The problem was related to my outdated version of web3.js. Thanks to you and everyone else for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to my outdated version of web3.js. After updating to V1.2.2 (from 1.0.0-beta.34) the problem was solved. There was a [Github issue describing the bug](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1403).

Answer (score 1):

For me it works fine on remix. I have run your code as is with no changes on remix and it shows the emitted value as true(Input: 1).

[image: True: when given 1]

Also it works prefectly well for false too(Input: 5).
[image: False when given 5]

So maybe if you gave more information like the version of solidity compiler, IDE you are using and the network the contract is being deployed, then maybe there would be a better shot at understanding the problem.

**New here!** Any suggestions would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Hi vteja711, thanks for your support. In Remix I don't have issues either. Just added my web3 code above.

Comment: The problem was related to my outdated version of web3.js. Thanks to you and everyone else for helping.